# Linux email client to connect to exchange server 2007

Tags: linux, email, exchange

My company just moved all our emails to an exchange server 2007.
I know there is an extension to connect to an exchange server for evolution but it doesn't seem to be compatible with the 2007 version.

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I manage to connect to the exchange server using [DavMail](http://davmail.sourceforge.net/)

> Ever wanted to get rid of Outlook ?
>   DavMail is a POP/IMAP/SMTP/Caldav/LDAP
>   exchange gateway allowing users to use
>   any mail/calendar client (e.g.
>   Thunderbird with Lightning or Apple
>   iCal) with an Exchange server, even
>   from the internet or behind a firewall
>   through Outlook Web Access. DavMail
>   now includes an LDAP gateway to
>   Exchange global address book to allow
>   recipient address completion in mail
>   compoze window and full calendar
>   support with attendees free/busy
>   display.

[image: DavMail graph]

Answer (score 1):

There are some others such as [KMail](http://userbase.kde.org/Kmail) and [Mailody](http://www.mailody.net/) (both for KDE), which advertise Exchange support, although on numerous sites I've found that either [IMAP must be enabled](http://techlogbook.wordpress.com/2008/05/06/acessing-exchange-2007-using-imap-from-kmail/) or certain features such as the Exchange Calendar would not work -- which is vital in the workplace if you need to receive notices of meetings and such.

A similar question was brought up on Slashdot [a little while ago](http://ask.slashdot.org/article.pl?sid=08/09/23/1642241), and judging by the comments it appears that a virtual machine of Windows running Outlook is the way to go if you want to ensure compatibility.